# Request to burn [updateapplicationcontext]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There are only 3 questions tagged with [updateapplicationcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updateapplicationcontext).

- [WatchKit:Delay when phone sends response to watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081292/watchkitdelay-when-phone-sends-response-to-watch)
- [Send Dictionary via updateApplicationContext from Watch to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586569/send-dictionary-via-updateapplicationcontext-from-watch-to-iphone)
- [updateApplicationContext not reaching Watch (device) but well simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396688/updateapplicationcontext-not-reaching-watch-device-but-well-simulator)

Do we need to have a tag for each specific method used to transfer information between paired iOS/watchOS devices?

**More details:**

[watchconnectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchconnectivity) and [wcsession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcsession) tags for `updateApplicationContext` questions already exist, and those 3 questions are *already* tagged with `WatchConnectivity`.

- There currently are 73 [WatchConnectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html) questions.

  *`WCSession` is a member of this framework.*
- There currently are 26 [WCSession class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html) questions.

  *`updateApplicationContext` is an instance method of this class.*

*This question is specifically about the `updateApplicationContext` tag.  Please reserve discussion about the `WCSession` tag for another question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 questions isn't much to burninate, I just edited them out of the questions that had them.

The questions themselves were mediocre at best, and certainly didn't justify the creation of the tag.

Comment: Thanks!  I would have done the same, but thought I should ask first before taking action.